# Как сверстать содержание с точками, чтобы точки не исчезали при переносе слов?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сверстать содержание с точками(как на картинке)?. Что бы при сжатии ширины слова переносились, а точки доставали прямо до нижнего слова(чтобы не оставалось пустого пространства, где отмечено красным). Нужно чтобы все было как на картинке.

Comment: Такой вопрос, а где сама картинка?

Comment: Где хоть строчка кода? С двух аккаунтов одни и те же вопросы и нигде нет ваших попыток.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, наверное.

```css
.table {
  display: block;
}

.table .lvl {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; 
}

.table .lvl:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.table .lvl .label,
.table .lvl .value {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 120px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.table .lvl .label > span,
.table .lvl .value > span {
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  background: white;
}

.table .lvl .value {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="lvl">
    <div class="label">
      <span>Фамилия</span>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <span>Мамай</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lvl">
    <div class="label">
      <span>С переносом на другую строку</span>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <span>Работает</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lvl">
    <div class="label">
      <span>И даже так</span>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <span>С переносом на другую строку</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```